# Can't install p2 profile using AntScript

Tags: eclipse, ant, rcp

I am writing AntScript to install the plug-in I made based on Eclipse Mars2.

I did copy & paste the plug-in I made into Eclipse/Plugins, but I think I need to install the p2 profile.

In the Ganymede version, you could just move it to the Plugins directory, but Mars2 doesn't. I don't think putting it in the Dropins directory is a good idea.

Here is the script I wrote:

destination is the current directory where eclipse.exe is located.

#### Script1

```
<exec executable="${destination}/eclipse.exe">
            <arg value="-application"/>
            <arg value="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director"/>
            <arg value="-repository"/>
            <arg value="http://aaa.com/update/bbb/3.x"/>
            <arg value="-installIU"/>
            <arg value="a.b.c.d.product"/>
            <arg value="-tag"/>
            <arg value="InitialState"/>
            <arg value="-destination"/>
            <arg value="${destination}"/>
            <arg value="-profile"/>
            <arg value="SDKProfile"/>
            <arg value="-profileProperties"/>
            <arg value="org.eclipse.update.install.feature=true"/>
            <arg value="-bundlepool"/>
            <arg value="${destination}"/>
            <arg value="-p2.os"/>
            <arg value="win32"/>
            <arg value="-p2.ws"/>
            <arg value="gtk"/>
            <arg value="-p2.arch"/>
            <arg value="x86_64"/>
            <arg value="-roaming"/>
        </exec>
```

#### Script2

```
<java
           taskname="install"
           jar="${destination}/plugins/a.b.*.jar"
           dir="${destination}"
           fork="true"
           failonerror="true">
           <arg value="-application"/>
           <arg value="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director"/>
           <arg value="-metadataRepository"/>
           <arg value="file:${destination},jar:file:${destination}/a.b.*.jar\!/"/>
           <arg value="-artifactRepository"/>
           <arg value="file:${destination},jar:file:${target-home}/a.b.*.jar\!/"/>
           <arg value="-installIU"/>
           <arg value="a.b.c.d.product"/>
           <arg value="-destination"/>
           <arg value="${destination}"/>
           <arg value="-profile"/>
           <arg value="SDKProfile"/>
           <arg value="-profileProperties"/>
           <arg value="org.eclipse.update.install.features=true"/>
           <arg value="-p2.os"/>
           <arg value="win32"/>
           <arg value="-p2.ws"/>
           <arg value="win32"/>
           <arg value="-p2.arch"/>
           <arg value="x86_64"/>
           <arg value="-vmargs"/>
           <arg value="-Declipse.p2.data.area=${destination}/p2"/>
        </java>
```

Both scripts do not install the p2 profile normally.

Please advise if there is any reference material.

Comment: Eclipse Mars is 7 years and 19 releases old

Comment: @greg-449 I know Mars2 is an outdated version.

That answer doesn't do anything to solve this question.

Comment: That is why it is just a comment., **not** an answer. But since this code is ancient it is unlikely that anyone will remember what worked and what didn't so long ago. Especially since most build things are done using [tag:tycho] these days.

Comment: What happens *instead*?